# How do you disable IPv6 on RPi4 permanently on Ubuntu 20.04 on RPi4B+?

Tags: pi-4, ubuntu

I've been wrestling with `sysctl` to get it to keep iPv6 disabled and find it works fine if I set it up like so:

```
$ cat /etc/sysctl.d/10-ipv6-off.conf
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6=1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.disable_ipv6=1
```

And then reload `sysctl`:

```
$ sysctl --system
```

But after rebooting I find that IPv6 gets re-enabled. How can I permanently disable IPv6?

Answer (score 2):

So what ended up working in this situation was to simply tell the kernel to disable IPv6 during boot. To accomplish this I merely added this string `ipv6.disable=1` to the `cmdline.txt` file in `/boot.

```
$ cat /boot/firmware/cmdline.txt
net.ifnames=0 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=LABEL=writable rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait fixrtc ipv6.disable=1
```

After doing so you can confirm that the kernel no longer provides access to IPv6 by looking in this directory:

```
$ ls /proc/sys/net/
core  ipv4  netfilter  unix
```

When IPv6 is enabled, the sub-directory, `ipv6` shows up in this location.

You can also check to make sure none of your NIC interfaces have `inet6` on them as well:

```
$ ip a l | grep inet6
$
```

#### References

- [How to Really Disable IPv6 on Raspberry PI](https://www.howtoraspberry.com/2020/04/disable-ipv6-on-raspberry-pi/)